# iOS - how to handle orientation changes in custom table cells

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, orientation

I have subclassed UITableViewCell to make a custom cell for a tableView. I add text and images to the cell's contentView.

Everything looks great in landscape mode (iPad), but no so much when I rotate to portrait. Where is the best place to handle orientation changes so that all the table cells can reposition the contents in its contentView? Do I put this code in the TableViewController or in the UITableViewCell subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play with autoresizingMask of your cell's views to see that maybe the proper result can be achieved automatically. If that doesn't work out, in your tableView's willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation you can do:

```
NSArray* visibleCells = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:visibleCells withRowAnimation:NO];
```

Comment: the second parameter of `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` is not a `BOOL`; it is a `UITableViewRowAnimation` type

Comment: ok, I know this is an old topic, but...you are allowed to pass in a `BOOL` to that method; Apple has made it so that a `NO` will give you no animation, and a `YES` will give you an automatic animation (whatever that means).

Comment: This answer is still so useful. I have been trying to achieve this using 'viewWillLayoutSubviews' and using orientation code, but that was oncoming too much memory. This is great.